# How to write a "List<int[,]>" in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to make a C++ equivalent code of the following C# code, mainly because I'm following a tutorial that is in C#, and I'm more comfortable using C++. My thought process is maybe making an outer array, then allocating a new array into each index that represents a matrix size. Would this be okay or is there a better way to go about implementing this in C++?

```
// current C# code
List<int[,]> pieces;

pieces = new List<int[,]>();

/* I Piece */
pieces.Add(new int[4, 4] {
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {1, 1, 1, 1},
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0}
});

/* J Piece */
pieces.Add(new int[3, 3] {
    {0, 0, 1},
    {1, 1, 1},
    {0, 0, 0}
});

/* O Piece */
pieces.Add(new int[2, 2] {
    {1, 1},
    {1, 1}
});

/* S Piece */
pieces.Add(new int[3, 3] {
    {0, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 0}
});


/* T Piece */
pieces.Add(new int[3, 3] {
    {0, 1, 0},
    {1, 1, 1},
    {0, 0, 0}
});

/* Z Piece */
pieces.Add(new int[3, 3] {
    {1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 1},
    {0, 0, 0}
});
```

My initial code is making a matrix in an array. Since I'm not looking to change the number of "pieces" in the game itself, then a fixed array should be fine. So this is what I wrote as an equivalent. Obviously, it didn't work, saying it cannot be assigned to an entity of int:

```
int pieces [7];

//I piece
pieces [0] = new int [4][4];
pieces [0] = {
                {0, 0, 0, 0},
                {1, 1, 1, 1},
                {0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0}
             }

/* And so on for each piece */
```

Comment: Yeah, but I tried vector and it led to some...messy code that didn't work the way I wanted it to.

Comment: Edited in the code I thought up. Of course, it doesn't want to work like that.

Answer (score 3):

IMO a vector of vector of vectors seems a little cumbersome for such a simple construct.

I'd probably assume that everything is 4x4, the largest size, and just embed the pieces in that, in which case you'd have

```
#include <vector>
struct Piece { int v[4][4]; };
std::vector<Piece> pieces { 
     // I piece
     { {
        {0,0,0,0},
        {1,1,1,1},
        {0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0}
     } },
     // J piece
     { {
       {0, 0, 1},  // This is OK since extra element will be 0 initialised by default.
       {1, 1, 1},
       {0, 0, 0}
       // Dont need a row here either as it will be 0 initialised.
     } }
     //Others omitted for now..
  };
```

Or for non C++11 compliant compilers:

```
#include <vector>
struct Piece { int v[4][4]; };
Piece raw_pieces[] = {
     { {
        {0,0,0,0},
        {1,1,1,1},
        {0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0}
     } },
     { {
       {0, 0, 1},  // This is OK since extra element will be 0 initialised by default.
       {1, 1, 1},
       {0, 0, 0}
       // Dont need a row here either as it will be 0 initialised.
     } }
};


std::vector<Piece> pieces(raw_pieces, raw_pieces + sizeof(raw_pieces)/sizeof(Piece));
```

Comment: Apparently, initialization with {} aren't allowed for vectors of the matrix type, as quoted by visual studio.

Comment: You're correct - I've updated my answer by wrapping the array into a copy-constructable and {} intializable struct.

Comment: You can see that it compiles on a C++11 compiler here: http://liveworkspace.org/code/dc90329e0ea013ee9610328fc105871a$1215

Comment: I just don't know why it isn't working, even with the fix you made. Maybe there was some compiler update that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Its likely that you are not enabling C++11 mode (or that VS support for those features in C++11 are flakey). You can always build up the vector piece by piece if you need to, but the syntax will not be as nice.

Comment: Added a version that should work for non-C++11 compilers.

Comment: So in the end, I'll have to do something messy one way or another. lol Thanks for your help. I'll get to this tomorrow. I need to sleep.

Comment: If you dont need append / remove functionality then you could just use the `raw_pieces` array directly, and in that case you could remove the struct and go to using `int pieces[4][4][] = {...`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `std::list<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >` or, as suggested try  `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >`

Here's a full example with `vector<vector<vector<int>>>`, but keep in mind, you will have to compile like this: **`g++ -std=c++0x t.cpp`**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<vector<int>>> A = {
      {
        {0, 0, 0, 0},
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
      },
      {
        {0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 0}
      },
      {
        {1, 1},
        {1, 1}
      },
      {
        {0, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0}
      },
      {
        {0, 1, 0},
        {1, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 0}
      },
      {
        {1, 1, 0},
        {0, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 0}
      }
    };


    for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++) {
      for(int j=0;j<A[i].size();j++) {
        for(int k=0;k<A[i][j].size();k++) {
          std::cout<<A[i][j][k];
        };
        std::cout<<std::endl;
      };
      std::cout<<std::endl;
    };
}
```

Or, if you don't like initializing everything in one go, and you want to do it at runtime. you can always use the `push_back` method that `std::vector` comes with

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<vector<int>>> A;
    A.push_back(vector<vector<int>>(
      {
        {0, 0, 0, 0},
        {1, 1, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
      }
    ));


    A.push_back(vector<vector<int>>(
      {
        {0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 0}
      }
    ));

    A.push_back(vector<vector<int>>(
      {
        {1, 1},
        {1, 1}
      }
    ));

    A.push_back(vector<vector<int>>(
      {
        {0, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0}
      }
    ));


    A.push_back(vector<vector<int>>(
      {
        {0, 1, 0},
        {1, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 0}
      }
    ));

    A.push_back(vector<vector<int>>(
      {
        {1, 1, 0},
        {0, 1, 1},
        {0, 0, 0}
      }
    ));


    for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++) {
      for(int j=0;j<A[i].size();j++) {
        for(int k=0;k<A[i][j].size();k++) {
          std::cout<<A[i][j][k];
        };
        std::cout<<std::endl;
      };
      std::cout<<std::endl;
    };
}
```

Comment: C#'s List is actually more like C++'s std::vector (it's a contiguous array rather than a linked list), so that should be `vector<vector<vector<int>>>`.

Comment: Ugly, but it makes sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, that code you gave expects an expression in the initialization phase, which means that there's something wrong with how it's set up.

Comment: If the code which uses (iterates over) that vector (of vectors of vectors...) is performance sensitive this is a bad solution.  You're going to be hopping around in memory like a rabbit.

Comment: Sorry, looking at the OP I suppose the size is rather small.  Clunky, but iteration speed wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Your solution is fine, but with visual studio, the command line option must be different. In the end, it still said it expects an expression with your second initialization, too.